# How do I filter a dataframe by applying a condition to a column whose values are tuples?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have a dataframe whose column values are tuples.  Absent recreating the dataframe, is there a way of dealing with the dataframe as it is in order to filter the dataframe as per the example below:

To construct the dataframe (excuse the convoluted construction):

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['Fruit','Color','Firmness','Volume']
data = [['Apple','Green','Soft',5],
        ['Apple','Red','Firm',5],
        ['Blueberry','Blue','Soft',5],
        ['Blueberry','Blue','Soft',5],
        ['Pear','Green','Soft',5],
        ['Pear','Green','Firm',5]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=columns,index=[0,1,2,3,4,5])

def all_values(values):
    
    return tuple([value for value in values])

agg_dict = {'Color':all_values,'Firmness':all_values,'Volume':'sum'}

df = df.groupby(by='Fruit').agg(agg_dict)

df

            Color           Firmness        Volume
Fruit           
Apple       (Green, Red)    (Soft, Firm)    10
Blueberry   (Blue, Blue)    (Soft, Soft)    10
Pear        (Green, Green)  (Soft, Firm)    10
```

Now, what I am trying to achieve is to return a dataframe showing only the rows where the second value in the tuple is 'Firm'.  That would be the Apple row and the Pear row in this case.

Is there something similar to the .str.contains method that I can use in this instance? in order to filter the dataframe accordingly?  Or any other suitable method that can perform the filtering directly?

Thanks!

Update:

Here is one attempt that does at least show the desired result, but does not achieve the goal since I have had to specify the 'Soft' as the first part of the tuple and that should not be necessary.  It also feels like quite a hack:

```
df = df.where(df['Firmness'] == ('Soft', 'Firm')).dropna()

df

        Color           Firmness        Volume
Fruit           
Apple   (Green, Red)    (Soft, Firm)    10.0
Pear    (Green, Green)  (Soft, Firm)    10.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `agg` with if...else

```
out = df.groupby('Fruit').agg(lambda x : x.sum() if x.dtype==int else tuple(x))
Out[332]: 
                    Color      Firmness  Volume
Fruit                                          
Apple        (Green, Red)  (Soft, Firm)      10
Blueberry    (Blue, Blue)  (Soft, Soft)      10
Pear       (Green, Green)  (Soft, Firm)      10
```

Then for your question

```
out = out[out.Firmness.str[1]=='Firm']
out
Out[335]: 
                Color      Firmness  Volume
Fruit                                      
Apple    (Green, Red)  (Soft, Firm)      10
Pear   (Green, Green)  (Soft, Firm)      10
```

Answer (score 1):

For your question, using apply and lambda

`df[df.apply(lambda x:x.Firmness[1]=='Firm' , axis=1)]`